yt_dlp FileNotFoundError when Renaming Subtitle File
I’m using yt_dlp to download subtitles for a video, but I’m encountering a FileNotFoundError when attempting to rename the subtitle file. Here’s the relevant portion of my code:
import yt_dlp
import os

def download_video(self, url):
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': self.download_dir + '/%(id)s.%(ext)s',
        'writesubtitles': True,
        'subtitleslangs': ['en'],
        'writeautomaticsub': True,
        'skip_download': True,  # Do not download the video
        'quiet': True,
    }

    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url)
        try:
            vtt_fp = info_dict['requested_subtitles']['en']['filepath']
            if os.path.exists(vtt_fp):
                print(f"Subtitle file found: {vtt_fp}")
            else:
                print(f"Subtitle file not found: {vtt_fp}")
        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"Key error: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Issue:
I’m getting the following traceback:
  File "backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yt_dlp/downloader/common.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yt_dlp/downloader/common.py", line 270, in try_rename
    os.replace(old_filename, new_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './download/Auuk1y4DRgk.en.vtt.part' -> './download/Auuk1y4DRgk.en.vtt'

It seems like the os.replace function is trying to rename a .part file that doesn’t exist.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Check File Existence: I’ve verified that the file 5MgBikgcWnY.en.vtt.part exists in the ./download/ directory, but the function ydl.extract_info() errors out.
Verify Paths and Permissions: Paths and permissions seem correct, and I am using the latest version of yt_dlp.
The corresponding commandline yt-dlp command works:

yt-dlp --outtmpl "./download/%(id)s.%(ext)s" \
       --write-subs \
       --sub-lang "en" \
       --write-auto-subs \
       --no-download \
       --quiet \
       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MgBikgcWnY

with no error.
Questions:

Why is yt_dlp trying to rename a file that appears not to exist?
Are there any additional steps or configurations I should check to ensure the subtitle file is correctly downloaded and available?
How can I better handle or debug this issue to prevent the FileNotFoundError?

Additional Information:

yt_dlp version: 2024.8.6
Python version: Python 3.10.8
Operating System: macOS 14.0

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

How did you run this script?  Remember, Python doesn't look in the folder that contains the script.  It looks in the CURRENT directory.  If you do python src/xxx.py, then you're in the wrong directory.  Use print(os.getcwd()) to find that.

Hi Tim, thanks for the response! This was part of a library I made for a backend server. When I used the argument, 'nopart': True, the script passed without failure. Furthermore, I saw how the file [id].env.vtt.part was temporarily created and then deleted under the original script.

If you're running in a back-end server, it's probably as a different user.  Does that user have write access to the folders you're using?
